# Как сделать чтобы при клике фон у элемента менялся, а затем при клике по другому элементу фон у первого элемента удалялся

Tags: javascript

```js
class Dropdown {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onLabel = this.onLabel.bind(this);

    this.label = this.node.querySelector(".dropdown__label");

    this.label.addEventListener("click", this.onLabel, false);
  }

  isOpen() {
    return this.node.classList.contains("dropdown_open");
  }

  onLabel() {
    this.isOpen() ? this.node.classList.remove("dropdown_open") : this.node.classList.add("dropdown_open");
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown")].forEach(node => new Dropdown(node));

var dropdown__label = document.querySelector('.dropdown__label');
dropdown__label.onclick = function(){
 dropdown__label.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
.dropdown{
  position: relative; 
}
.dropdown:before{
  content: '';
  background-image: url('../img/select-bottom.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}
.dropdown_open .dropdown__list {
  display: block;

  
}
.dropdown_open{
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown_open:before{ 
 content: '';
  background-image: url('../img/select-top.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

.dropdown__list {
  display: none; }

.dropdown__label {
  position: relative; }

.dropdown__list {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px; }

.dropdown__item {
  padding: 0; }
  .dropdown__item a {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 36px;
    white-space: nowrap; }
    .dropdown__item a:hover {
      color: #e60146;
      text-decoration: none; }

.dropdown__label {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #f5f0eb;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
   }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">PANORAMIC</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">ACRA Mid-rise MMR</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">Muse Mid-rise MRL</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">Solon Premium Mid-rise MRL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">PANORAMIC</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">ACRA Mid-rise MMR</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">Muse Mid-rise MRL</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#">Solon Premium Mid-rise MRL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде включение "активного" класса выглядит так:

```js
const moo = document.getElementsByClassName('moo');
for(let i=0; i<moo.length; i++){
  moo[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    for(let u=0; u<moo.length; u++){
      moo[u].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.moo {margin: 5px;}
.active {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<button class="moo">Moo</button>
<button class="moo">Moo</button>
<button class="moo">Moo</button>
```

То же самое на jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.moo',function(){
  $('.moo').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Здесь логика нагляднее видна - после каждого клика, сперва попросту удаляем активный класс со всех кнопок, а потом добавляем этот же класс на текущую кликнутую.

P.s. если речь идет про удаление фона в случае клика вообще в любом месте, кроме как покрашенной кнопки, в таком случае всё проще, CSS — `.moo:focus {background:orange;}`

Comment: спасибо скажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при клике втором клике на тот же элемент он возвращал свой фон ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/t397g6hd/ - так. При клике сразу проверяем, есть ли в классе текущего кликнутого элемента совпадения match(/active/g). Если есть - убираем этот класс с текущего элемента. А если нет - убираем класс со всех остальных элементов, добавив активный на текущий элемент.

Comment: спасибо (какой-то текст ...)